# Remove Children and only use string value of enums when convert to data-table C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, datatable

I am wondering if anyone can help me I am trying to make a method which will convert lists into data tables but remove any child lists, arrays etc only keep the flat list with absolutely no children and if there was an enum, then take the string value of the enum value.

Updated Below:

```
    public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
        {
            if ( prop.PropertyType.GetInterface(typeof(IEnumerable<>).Name) != null &&
                 prop.PropertyType.GetInterface(typeof(IList<>).Name) != null &&
                 prop.PropertyType.GetInterface(typeof(ICollection<>).Name) != null)
            {
                if (prop.PropertyType.BaseType == typeof(Enum))
                {
                    table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, typeof(String));
                }
                else
                {
                    table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            {
                if (prop.PropertyType.GetInterface(typeof(IEnumerable<>).Name) != null &&
                     prop.PropertyType.GetInterface(typeof(IList<>).Name) != null &&
                     prop.PropertyType.GetInterface(typeof(ICollection<>).Name) != null)
                {
                    if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(Enum))
                    {
                      //  row[prop.Name] = Enum.GetName(typeof(prop.PropertyType), prop.GetValue(item));

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
                    }
                    table.Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }
        }
        return table;
    }
```

The problem I am having is how to remove the children (especially from rows) and how to if it is an enum take the enum string value only.

The purpose of this is create a datatable to which I am can pass to a stored procedure to insert into a SQL Server database,

By enum I mean

```
enum Test
{
   None,
   Hidden  = 2,
   Visible = 4
};
```

So instead of been type enum it will be changed to type string for example Visible. So the datatables column would be of type string.

Comment: Seems like XY problem. Sorry can you explain purpose of this method?

Comment: I have updated above, hope its clear